# php file upload works locally not on server

Tags: php, file-upload

Hi I am going from a xamp server on windows to a cpanel linux hosted server online.

My image upload script isn't working. I have set file perms on all files involved to 777 and that still doesn't help.

It seems the $_FILES['image1'] is empty.

Any ideas on what may cause this?

newProduct.php

```
    <form action="newProduct.CREATE.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image1" id="image1" />
```

newProduct.CREATE.php

```
    $directory = "img/products/";
    $image = $_FILES['image1'];
    $image1 = uploadImage($image, $directory);
```

Functions file:

```
    function uploadImage($image, $directory) {
    $file_name = $image['name'];
    $file_size = $image['size'];
    $file_tmp = $image['tmp_name'];
    $file_type= $image['type'];   
    echo $image['name'];
    $newName = convertFileToMD5($file_name);
    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$directory".$newName);

    $image = "$directory" . $newName;
    return $image;

}
```

Comment: Why do you think `$_FILES['image1']` is empty? What do you get if you `var_dump($_FILES);`?

Comment: it returns array(1) { ["file"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(0) "" ["type"]=> string(0) "" ["tmp_name"]=> string(0) "" ["error"]=> int(4) ["size"]=> int(0) } }

Comment: Can you check if the PHP has permissions to do FILE operations on the path in your Linux server box? Try to upload to other directory and if it works then, it must be a permission error. if it fails even there, check the FASTCGI setting on your webserver. Is it enabled?

Comment: How would you recommend to do that? It's a shared hosted server so I am quite limited.